# Variable interpolation in the shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a variable called `filepath=/tmp/name`.

To access the variable, I know that I can do this: `$filepath`

In my shell script I attempted to do something like this (the backticks are intended)

```
`tail -1 $filepath_newstap.sh`
```

This line fails, duuh!, because the variable is not called `$filepath_newstap.sh`

How do I append `_newstap.sh` to the variable name?

Please note that backticks are intended for the expression evaluation.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Use

```
"$filepath"_newstap.sh
```

or

```
${filepath}_newstap.sh
```

or

```
$filepath\_newstap.sh
```

`_` is a valid character in identifiers. Dot is not, so the shell tried to interpolate `$filepath_newstap`.

You can use `set -u` to make the shell exit with an error when you reference an undefined variable.

Comment: Maybe also mention `set -u` which causes the script to abort if you reference an undefined variable.

Comment: What is the difference between using `${}` and double quotes? Should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: @user31389: The difference is when the variable contains whitespace, then only double quotes work.

Comment: @choroba The variables _name_ or the variable _value_?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter: Variable name can never contain whitespace.

Comment: You can also spot-check one variable to break-if-empty like so: `"${check_me:?}"`

Answer (score 27):

Use curly braces around the variable name:

```
`tail -1 ${filepath}_newstap.sh`
```

Comment: Don't you need double quotes?

Comment: @michaelsnowden Not necessarily. To be safe, yes, but the question explicitly stated a path with no spaces and further suggested that the trouble was `$filepath_newstap.sh` being interpreted as `${filepath_newstap}.sh` rather than the intended `${filepath}_newstap.sh`, which would solve the problem.

Comment: @michaelsnowden That tells me nothing I'm not already aware of. Why do you think double quotes are required?

Comment: Because you're trying to do string interpolation, and you need double quotes for that

Comment: @michaelsnowden Parameter expansion happens either in double quotes or outside of quotes completely. Single quotes or separating characters with quotes or other characters not valid in identifiers are the only way to prevent parameter expansion. For example, `"$filepath"_foo` and `${filepath}_foo` would both expand to `/tmp/name_foo`. However, `'$filepath'_foo`, `"$"filepath_foo`, and `$"filepath"_foo` would all avoid expansion completely. This is why `export PATH=$PATH:$addpath` works to add `:$addpath` (which would be subject to parameter expansion) to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Incidentally, both of the other two answers contain the same response. The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17622165/539810), however, also provides alternatives and an explanation for the behavior described by the OP.

Comment: @michaelsnowden You're probably confusing backticks ( `\`` ) with single-quotes ( `'` )

Answer (score 5):

In Bash:

```
tail -1 ${filepath}_newstap.sh
```