# Strange behavior of shell output file ( Linux )

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Do you know why below shell script just generates the output file named 'Loading_EMP.sql' instead of 'Loading_1_EMP.sql'?

```
#!/bin/bash

JOBID="1"
TABLE="EMP"

echo 'test'  > Loading_$JOBID_$TABLE.sql; 

# Output
Loading_EMP.sql

# Expected Output
Loading_1_EMP.sql
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable interpolation in shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622106/variable-interpolation-in-shell)

Comment: @jackrabbit : Apart from the variable interpolation issue, there is also an issue of missing double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo 'test'  > Loading_${JOBID}_${TABLE}.sql;
```

should do it, or better

```
echo 'test'  > "Loading_${JOBID}_${TABLE}.sql" # to avoid word splitting
```

In `Loading_$JOBID_$TABLE`, shell trates `$JOBID_` as a single variable and since it is not set, it substitutes `$JOBID_` with nothing resulting in `Loading_EMP.sql`

---

<sup>This [[ answer ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748880/1620779) must read for you.</sup>

Comment: I understand that now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, have a great weekend then ;)

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter thinks you are referring to a variable named `JOBID_`. Enclose the name with `{}`.

```
echo 'test'  > Loading_${JOBID}_$TABLE.sql
```

Comment: You might consider double quoting `Loading_${JOBID}_$TABLE.sql` to accommodate filenames with spaces.

Comment: Those only matter if you have spaces or other weird characters. His script clearly does not suffer from that.

Answer (score 1):

`_` is not a special character in shell. So the shell sees this as you echoing a `$JOBID_` variable, which is undefined, and thus empty. Instead, you should explicitly show the shell what your variables are by using `{}`:

```
echo 'test'  > Loading_${JOBID}_${TABLE}.sql;
# Here -----------------^-----^--^-----^
```